# Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\Lambda(k)}{k}-\ln(n)=-\gamma $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, limits

How do I prove$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\Lambda(k)}{k}-\ln(n)=-\gamma $$

Where  $\Lambda(k)$ is the Von-Mangoldt function, and gamma is the euler gamma constant

Comment: Theorem 424 in Hardy and Wright, page 348.

Comment: Thanks, can I get a link, I don't have a copy of the book

Comment: That's why there are libraries.

Comment: I cant get to a library, that is why I asked for a link

Comment: @Will, I have the 6th edition. Theorem 424 has relocated to page 462, and doesn't mention $\gamma$; it just has $O(1)$.

Comment: See too 3.3 of this (.ps) [paper](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Gamma/gammaFormulas.ps).

Answer (score 4):

Xavier Gourdon and Pascal Sebah (in $3.3$ of ["Collection of formulae for Euler’s constant $\gamma$"](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Gamma/gammaFormulas.pdf)) propose to use this [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function#Dirichlet_series) :
$$-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {\Lambda(k)}{k^s},\quad s>1$$

that they rewrite as :
$$\zeta(s)+\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {\Lambda(k)-1}{k^s},\quad s>1$$ 
before taking the limits as $s\to 1$ and deducing :
$$2\,\gamma=-\sum_{k\ge1}\frac {\Lambda(k)-1}k$$
(the existence of the limit at the right could be questionable...)

The limit at the left may indeed be obtained using (for $|\epsilon|\ll 1$ and $\gamma_1$ a [Stieltjes constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants)) :

- $\displaystyle \zeta(1+\epsilon)=\frac 1{\epsilon}+\gamma-\gamma_1 \,\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)\ $ and
- $\displaystyle \zeta'(1+\epsilon)=-\frac 1{\epsilon^2}-\gamma_1+O(\epsilon)$

so that $\ \displaystyle \frac{\zeta'(1+\epsilon)}{\zeta(1+\epsilon)}=-\frac 1{\epsilon}\frac{1+\gamma_1\,\epsilon^2}{1+\gamma\,\epsilon}+O(\epsilon)=-\frac 1{\epsilon}+\gamma+O(\epsilon)\ $
and $\ \displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \zeta(s)+\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=2\gamma\ $ as required.

To get your limit we will just need the additional [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) of $\gamma$ :
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k\right)$$
rewrite the previous limit as :
$$-2\,\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {\Lambda(k)-1}k\right)$$
and combine these two results to conclude :
$$-\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\log(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {\Lambda(k)}k\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If you can show $$\sum_{n\le x}\log n=x\log x+O(x)$$ and $$\sum_{n\le x}\log n=\sum_{n\le x}[x/n]\Lambda(n)$$ then you can get $$\sum_{n\le x}{\Lambda(n)\over n}=\log x+O(1)$$ which isn't as strong as what you want but is in the same ballpark. This is the essence of Hardy & Wright Theorem 424 (6th edition).

Comment: Got your note. Evidently I had a brain relocation, the fifth edition does not mention $\gamma$ either, just what you quote. So now we've got to wonder where the $\gamma$ came from, and whether it's correct.